# Violent Python: port inputs not being seperated

Tags: python

So I'm learning Python and hacking at the same time from "Violent Python" and I ran into a problem
Here's my code:

```
import optparse
import socket
from socket import *
from threading import *

screenLock = Semaphore(value = 1)

def connScan(tgtHost, tgtPort):
    try:
        connSkt = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        connSkt.connect((tgtHost, tgtPort))
        connSkt.send('ViolentPython\r\n')
        results = connSkt.recv(100)
        screenLock.acquire()
        print '[+]%d/tcp open' %tgtPort
        print '[+] ' + str(results)
    except:
        screenLock.acquire()
        print '[-]%d/tcp closed' %tgtPort
    finally:
        screenLock.release()
        connSkt.close()
def portScan(tgtHost, tgtPorts):
    try:
        tgtIP = gethostbyname(tgtHost)
    except:
        print "[-] Cannot resolve '%s': Unknown host" %tgtHost
        return
    try:
        tgtName = gethostbyaddr(tgtIP)
        print '\n[+] Scan Results for ' +tgtName[0]
    except:
        print '\n[+] Scan Results for ' +tgtIP
    setdefaulttimeout(10)
    for tgtPort in tgtPorts:
        print 'Scanning port ' +tgtPort
        t = Thread(target=connScan, args=(tgtHost, int(tgtPort)))
        t.start()
def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser('usage %prog ' +\
    '-H <target host> -p <target port>')
    parser.add_option('-H', dest='tgtHost', type='string', \
        help='specify target host')
    parser.add_option('-p', dest='tgtPort', type='string', \
        help='specify target port[s] seperated by a comma')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    tgtHost = options.tgtHost
    tgtPorts = str(options.tgtPort).split(', ')
    if (tgtHost == None) | (tgtPorts[0] == None):
        print parser.usage
        exit(0)
    portScan(tgtHost, tgtPorts)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Running the program I get the following error message:

```
  File "port_scanner.py", line 54, in <module>
    main()
  File "port_scanner.py", line 52, in main
    portScan(tgtHost, tgtPorts)
  File "port_scanner.py", line 37, in portScan
    t = Thread(target=connScan, args=(tgtHost, int(tgtPort)))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '21,'
```

Can anyone please help? I'm still new at this but my guess is Python isn't separating the different ports I'm inputting by running this command:

```
python port_scanner.py -H 74.207.244.221 -p 21, 22, 80
```

The ip I'm targeting is scanme.org and is made for scanning. Thanks!

Comment: I think that `optparse` parses the string upto the first whitespace. Try this: `python port_scanner.py -H 74.207.244.221 -p "21, 22, 80"`

Comment: You can launch it with python port_scanner.py -H 74.207.244.221 -p 21,22,80

Comment: What Daniel said, but you would also need to change the code to split to use `","` instead of `", "`. `int()` can skip whitespace, so it should work fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you are misunderstanding how your command line is being parsed.

You pass in:

```
python port_scanner.py -H 74.207.244.221 -p 21, 22, 80
```

which means that Python sees:

```
['-H', '74.207.244.221', '-p', '21,', '22,', '80']
```

and the `optparse.OptionParser` thus parses *just* `'21,'` as the value for the `-p` switch. As a result, `options.tgtPort` is set to `'21,'`, and `.split(', ')` on that value results in `['21,']` because there is *no* `', '` (comma and space) in that input string.

To include spaces in an argument, use quoting on the command line:

```
python port_scanner.py -H 74.207.244.221 -p "21, 22, 80"
```

but you really want to adjust your command-line parsing to split *just* on commas and tolerate spaces instead:

```
tgtPorts = [p.strip() for p in options.tgtPort.split(',')]
```

Another thing to understand is that splitting a string using `.split()` will result in a list with *at least* one element:

```
>>> 'foo'.split(',')
['foo']
```

so your test for `tgtPorts[0] == None` will always be `False`. Note that the normal Python idiom is to use `is` for `None` instead (`tgtPorts[0] is None`) because `None` is a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma in the value of the port, so Python can't convert the string into integer smoothly. You can reproduce this exception in interpreter easily:

```
>>> int("2,")

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
int("2,")
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2,'
>>> int("2")
2
```

To remove the comma, simply don't pass it in at the command line. Or if you really have to, process the input so that it can be converted.

Answer (score 0):

if you change:

```
t = Thread(target=connScan, args=(tgtHost, int(tgtPort)))
```

to

```
t = Thread(target=connScan, args=(tgtHost, int(tgtPort.strip(","))))
```

it should work, not sure where in the argument parsing it went wrong though..